# Display all the values of x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these data

```
cc<-structure(list(Cycle = c("Average", "Average", "Average", "Average", 
"Average", "Average", "Average", "Average", "Average", "Average", 
"Average", "Average"), name = structure(1:12, levels = c("Die 1", 
"Pro 1", "Est 1", "Met 1", "Die 2", "Pro 2", "Est 2", "Met 2", 
"Die 3", "Pro 3", "Est 3", "Met 3"), class = "factor"), value = c(100, 
101, 97, 99, 100, 101.788432267884, 97.2, 99.6194824961948, 100, 
102, 97.5, 99), min = c(98.3337514142342, 99.3337514142342, 95.3337514142342, 
97.3337514142342, 98.3337514142342, 100.122183682119, 95.5337514142342, 
97.953233910429, 98.3337514142342, 100.333751414234, 95.8337514142342, 
97.3337514142342), max = c(101.666248585766, 102.666248585766, 
98.6662485857658, 100.666248585766, 101.666248585766, 103.45468085365, 
98.8662485857658, 101.285731081961, 101.666248585766, 103.666248585766, 
99.1662485857658, 100.666248585766)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and my plot but I cannot fit all the values of the x-axis in plot.

```
cc%>%ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_blank() +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 15) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max ), width = 0.05, size = 0.4) + # Add error bars
  scale_y_continuous('% Weight relative to die', limits = c(92, 104), breaks = seq(96, 109, by = 4)) +
  labs(title = 'Weighted across EC-3 cycles', x = 'Phase') +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),  # Bold axis titles
        legend.position = "right",
        plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5),
        plot.title.position = 'plot'
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Try changing the call to `coord_cartesian()` to say `coord_cartesian(expand = 0.05)`

Comment: Another option would be to increase the plot margin on the right, e.g. `+ theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 5.5, r = 22, b = 5.5, l = 5.5)` where 5.5pt is the default for `theme_classic()`.

Comment: You can also use `element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)` to angle the axis labels if you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Just allocate more space when defined.

`cc<-structure(list(Cycle = c("Average", "Average", "Average", "Average",  "Average", "Average", "Average", "Average", "Average", "Average",  "Average", "Average"), name = structure(1:12, levels = c("Die 1",  "Pro 1", "Est 1", "Met 1", "Die 2", "Pro 2", "Est 2", "Met 2",  "Die 3", "Pro 3", "Est 3", "Met 3     "), class = "factor"), value = c(100,  101, 97, 99, 100, 101.788432267884, 97.2, 99.6194824961948, 100,  102, 97.5, 99), min = c(98.3337514142342, 99.3337514142342, 95.3337514142342,  97.3337514142342, 98.3337514142342, 100.122183682119, 95.5337514142342,  97.953233910429, 98.3337514142342, 100.333751414234, 95.8337514142342,  97.3337514142342), max = c(101.666248585766, 102.666248585766,  98.6662485857658, 100.666248585766, 101.666248585766, 103.45468085365,  98.8662485857658, 101.285731081961, 101.666248585766, 103.666248585766,  99.1662485857658, 100.666248585766)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df",`